# Azure Graph API - RemoveServicePrincipal()

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to use RemoveServicePrincipal to remove a temporary service account that is no longer needed after the program closes, and I can't seem to find any documentation on this anywhere with regards to what parameters are required.

Does anyone know where I can find info on this or an example that I can use as a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194113.aspx

Comment: I was hoping to find something that didn't use PowerShell. Thanks though.